# How to release app to heroku with docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, heroku

I've an application NodeJS and I would like to run it on Heroku.

I use the docker CLI with these command :

```
docker build -t registry.heroku.com/my-app/web .
docker login --username=_ --password=MYTOKEN registry.heroku.com
docker push registry.heroku.com/my-app/web
```

All of these commands are running good but my app is not released on heroku.

What is wrong ? Why my app is not released on heroku ?

I cannot use the heroku CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heroku Container Runtime won't release images on `docker push`. That action is required, but only to upload images on the Heroku Platform.

You need to use the `heroku container:release` command, or the Heroku API to release those new images on your app.

See the Heroku Documentation about [releasing docker images](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#releasing-an-image).